# CakePHP 2.2.8 helper problems

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using this version of the framework, but when I write a helper like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->css('forms');
?>
```

It outputs this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/adm/admin/index.php/users/css/forms.css" />
```

instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/adm/admin/app/webroot/css/forms.css" />
```

Any idea why?

Comment: check that how they are using generic css :) in package

Comment: The problem with the helpers is ... they are not workin properly .. and writting erroneus HTML code,  still i dont know if i have to set something else.. in echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login') ); i get <form action="/adm/admin/index.php/users/users/login" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> as a result , and then an error like users action is not defined see that users is placed twice.. when the action is just 'login'.

Comment: I finally got it working properly ... i uncommented the line Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME')); in app/Config/core.php thank you very much ..

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with helper buddy .You need to configure your app to rewrite mode. In this case if you wanna use htaccess use [This](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)(Rewrite mode) if its hard for you to configure it to [This](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl). By doing this all problem with URL will be sorted.